# How to use client side javascript variables as array index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

So I'm trying to teach myself to make a website.  I'm using node and expressJS server side to send the template to the client like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var cityData = require("../public/cityData/paris.json");

    res.render('index', {
        cityData : cityData 
     });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In this case I'm just passing a JSON file with information about the city of Paris that I want to display to the client.  It has an array of image URLs that I can use for pictures.  My issue is that I only want to show one image at a time and change the image to the next one when a key is pressed (or a button if necessary, but preference for key).

My issue comes on the client side, I can get the JSON object and generate the page based on it if I use a value eg [0] in the place of the "index" variable, but if I have it setup as shown, index is "undefined".  So my question is, how does one make a variable that will exist clientside and allow me to rerender the page with a new picture, is that even possible?  I've been reading stack overflow for hours and nothing seems to be what I want.

Thanks.

HTML code  --->

```
<% include templates/head.ejs %>

<script "text/javascript" >
    var index = 0;
</script>

<body>
    <!-- This imports the naviagtion template I made -->
    <% include templates/navigation.ejs %>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <% include templates/sidebar.ejs %>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id = "page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- This imports an image -->
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "text-center">
                         <img id = "imgArea" src = <%- cityData.imageUrl[index] %> class = "img-rounded col-xs-12 col-md-6" width = "device-width">
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
        });
        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            index ++;
            document.getElementById("imgArea").innerHTML = cityData.imageURL[index];
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You mean you want render the templates on the client side? Here is an offical example, how to do it. https://github.com/tj/ejs/blob/master/examples/client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS runs on the server. It's the server who renders the webpage and then the variable is lost on the client. I would recommend a for loop to include all images when you render the index.ejs BUT put a class of hidden on all images except the first one. Then using some front-end javascript magic you can view images side by side. You can use jquery/bootstrap for that. ( Bootstrap carousel is a nice example ).

In order to store variables in the front-end you can use this:

```
<script>
var frontEndVar = <%= EJSvar %>;
</script>
```

Some times this will simply evaluate to [object Object] so you might want to first use JSON.stringify on the server side

Comment: Ah that is a good solution and I'll probably use it.  But, for future reference my question still, is it possible to store a variable client side and access and change it with javascript snippets?

Comment: Edited answer to help you do what you asked